# max() give "int" not callable error in my function

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a problem using max() inside my function. When a create a list with integers, max function works good. However when a create a list in my function and then using max() with my integer list then it gives "**TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**" error.
Where am I wrong and how can I fix it?

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5] # A simple list
>>> max(a) # It works fine
>>> 5
>>> def palen(num):
...     min = 10**(num-1)
...     max = (10**num)-1
...     a=[] # Another list
...     mul=0
...     for i in range(max,min-1,-1):
...         for j in range (max,min-1,-1):
...             mul=i*j
...             if str(mul)==str(mul)[::-1]:
...                 a.append(mul)
...     return max(a)
...
>>> palen(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<input>", line 11, in palen
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: You have named a variable max: `max = (10**num)-1`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you **redefine** max as a int number with

```
max = (10**num)-1
```

so you can not Call a number to help you get the max value of a list.
Change the variable name will be ok:

```
def palen(num):
  min_num = 10**(num-1)
  max_num = (10**num)-1
  a=[] # Another list
  mul=0
  for i in range(max_num,min_num-1,-1):
    for j in range (max_num,min_num-1,-1):
      mul=i*j
      if str(mul)==str(mul)[::-1]:
        a.append(mul)
  return max(a)

print palen(2)
```

Answer (score 5):

If we use max as variable name in earlier part of program, then we will encounter this problem. Advise is to not use max/min as variable name. Solution is to rename earlier variables with name max.

```
x=[1,2,3]
max(x)
```

Output:3

```
max=20
x=[1,2,3]
max(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On line 6 of your readout you define a variable called `max`. This shadows the pointer to `max()`.
This is why you can't use the `max()` function anymore.
You need to rename your variable `max` on line 6 and everywhere else you use it to fix this.

For more information on namespaces in Python see this interesting page I just found: http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/

Comment: That mistake is called shadowing ^^

Answer (score 0):

do not use max in any naming while programming
else if you can delete max variable from memory if not in use

use `del(max)`  before calling `max(arr)` or similar situations