# Python TypeError: 'float' object is not callable when using Min() Max()

Tags: python-3.x

I kept getting TypeError: 'float' object is not callable when I try to get the Min and Max value from my list using min() and max().  Any idea how to fix this please?

Here is my code:

```
count=0
sum=0.0
max=0.0
min=0.0
list=[]

while True:
    sval=input('enter a number: ')
    if sval=='done':
        break

    try:
        fval=float(sval)
    except:
        print('invalid number')
        continue
    sum = sum+fval
    count=count+1
    list.append(fval)
    print(list)
max_number = max(list)
min_number = min(list)

print(sum, count, sum/count, max_number, min_number)
```

Comment: You overwrote `min` and `max` with float zeros. You also overwrote `list` and `sum`. Name your variables differently than built-ins. You don't need to count manually the number of values you appended because it will end up being `len(list_)` and you don't need to sum manually because it's `sum(list_)`.

Comment: thanks so much! it's working after i removed max = 0.0 and min=0.0 at the start of the program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [max() give "int" not callable error in my function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815199/max-give-int-not-callable-error-in-my-function)